# Matching everything after first pipe character in Javascript RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
"http://www.yahoo.com/abc/123|X|Y|Z"
```

I need to get everything after the first pipe with a regex.  So I would want to be left with this string:

```
"X|Y|Z"
```

How do I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Without a regex: `str.split("|").slice(1).join("|")`

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer, if you want it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer:

Shockingly, regexes are not the answer to everything.

[image: xkcd]
> [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1171/)

Try this:

```
str.split("|").slice(1).join("|");
```

This splits your string on pipe characters, slices off the first item, then joins the rest with pipes again.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simpler regex **/\|(.*)/**

```
var str = "http://www.yahoo.com/abc/123|X|Y|Z";
var aryMatches = str.match(/\|(.*)/);
// aryMatches[1] will have your results
```

[regex explaination](http://regex101.com/r/zP0kB8/1)

Answer (score 0):

First group contains the expected characters,

```
^.*?\|(.*)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kF4pU2/6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[^|]*\|(.*)/
```

And use matched group #1 for your match.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the splitting and splicing, just use a substring

```
var str = "http://www.yahoo.com/abc/123|X|Y|Z";
str.substr(str.indexOf("|") + 1);
```